# Redirect if prefix of path is missing

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having troubles writing a seemingly easy RewriteRule/Condition:

`example.com` should redirect to `example.com/de`.
`example.com/de` shouldn't redirect.
`example.com/en` shouldn't redirect.
`example.com/foobar` should redirect to `example.com/de/foobar`.
`example.com/de/foobar` shouldn't redirect.
`example.com/en/foobar` shouldn't redirect.

What I have is this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(de|en)/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%{HTTP_HOST}/de%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But I always get too many redirects.

Comment: Any specific reasons of using `%{ENV:protossl}`?

Comment: @anubhava not really. I wrote this using a RewriteRule of Drupal7 as a base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!(de|en)) /de%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This doesn't redirect at all.